# window.postMessage wait for response before code execution

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, synchronous, postmessage

I try to make the example the more simple, in realty my problem is in a more complex context.
I have an html page (parent.htm) containing an iframe (child.htm). The html page and the iframe are in different domains so I use window.postMessage to communicate from one to the other.

Here is the code of parent.htm :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            if (window.addEventListener){
                window.addEventListener("message",getMessage,false);
            } else if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
                window.attachEvent("onmessage",getMessage);
            }

            function getMessage(event){
                if(event.data=="getCity"){
                    window.myIframe.postMessage("London","*");
                }
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="height:100%;width:100%">
            <iframe name="myIframe" src="child.htm"></iframe>
        </div>      
  </body>
</html>
```

And the code of child.htm

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            if (window.addEventListener){
                window.addEventListener("message",getValue,false);
            } else if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
                window.attachEvent("onmessage",getValue);
            }

            var returnValue="";

            function getValue(event){
                returnValue=event.data;
            }

            function getCityFromTop(){
                top.postMessage("getCity","*"); 
                return returnValue;
            }
        </script>
    </head>     
    <body>
        <a href="javascript:alert(getCityFromTop())">Get city from top</a>
        <br/>
        <a href="javascript:alert(returnValue)">Show city after call</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

So when I click on the "Get city from top" link :

1. child.htm calls top.postMessage
2. parent.htm receives the message
3. parent.htm calls myIframe.postMessage to send the response
4. child.htm receives the response and store it in returnVal

My problem is that postMessage call is asynchronous. So in the code :

```
var returnValue="";

function getValue(event){
    returnValue=event.data;
}

function getCityFromTop(){
    top.postMessage("getCity","*"); 
    return returnValue;
}
```

When I return returnValue, returnValue is not yet changed by the response received (points 3 and 4 above).

If I click on "Show city after call" after clicking on "Get city from top" link, "London" is alerted, as expected.

My question : how can I handle this? Is there a way to wait the response before continuing code execution in function getCityFromTop()?

Comment: No. `postMessage` is one-directional. You'd have to wait for another message to come bak.

Comment: And is there a workaround to "pause" until returnValue is different from "" ?

Comment: if there's nothing else to execute, by definition the worker will 'pause'. then when the message comes back you can start up again.

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure to understand your response. If you have time can you give a quick example in the context of my code? thanks a lot.